# What exactly is Steam doing when it says, "Preparing to Launch <GAME NAME HERE>"?

Tags: steam

Whenever I launch a game using Steam, it always says, "Preparing to Launch ________________". What exactly is it doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing:

1. Verifying the game is legit (DRM).
2. Verifying the game is up-to-date.
3. Verifying the requirements for the game (e.g. directx) are still met.

Although (3) should theoretically only be checked on the first run, I'm pretty sure it's actually checked on *every* run - I saw a few games that always show a brief "installing directx" line even after the first run. Maybe it is done to verify no hardware or software changes were made to the system that can break the game.

This is just a guess, though... if you want to know for sure, I suppose you can monitor the Steam process at the moment it is launched (e.g. with a network analyzer and some process monitor such as [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021)).

Comment: As of 3 - user might uninstall the DirectX/MSVS C++ runtime support between game runs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure #1 is only done the first time you install and maybe once every 30 days after.

Comment: I rather think is does it once per session. When I launch a game for the first time of the day, the "Preparing" is much longer that the following launches?

Comment: @Shadur: As far as I know, that's only true if you're in Offline mode.

Comment: @Powerlord Ah, fair enough.